# How to do regex validation in Jenkins pipeline file?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I tried to execute the shell commands and store the output result content to the string variable. From that string variable, i need to find and get whether the required decimal value using regular expression. Below is the code i tried. Job got failed continuously. Could anyone please help me to resolve this?

My output should be like "5.2.0".

```
node("10.6")
{
stage 'test' 
try
{   
def matcher = "5.2.0.123" =~ /^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?(\.[0-9]+)?/
if( matcher.matches() ) { echo "success"} 
}
catch(Exception e)
{ echo e
}
```

}

Comment: if your statement is true, you can return output like this: `"5.2.0.123".findAll(/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?(\.[0-9]+)?/)[0]`

Answer (score 1):

In your statement true, use `findAll` method to return the output from regex, like this:

```
​"5.2.0.123".findAll(/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?(\.[0-9]+)?/)[0]​
```